# Iterate over a list of lists, assert multiple conditions and render when true in Jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

I have the following variables to use in my Jinja template:

```py
list_python_version = [3, 9]
all_python_version = [
  [3, 8],
  [3, 9],
  [3, 10],
  [3, 11],
  [3, 12]
]
```

Is there a way to use a combination of Jinja filters and tests so it iterates over `all_python_version`, checks that both the first and second elements of the list are greater or equal than the elements of `list_python_version`, and when the conditions are met, it generates the string for `MAJOR.MINOR` version and joins all that are valid in a single string?

This way, considering the variables above, the rendered template should give `3.9, 3.10, 3.11, 3.12`?

I have tried the following expression:

```
{{
  all_python_version |
  select('[0] >= minimal_python_version[0] and [1] >= minimal_python_version[1]') |
  join('.') |
  join(', ')
}}
```

But it will fail since the `select` filter asks for a function, and so far I have not found in Jinja's documentation any hint as to how we can use conditionals to filter values inside an expression.

Alternatively, the solution could encompass a `for` loop in Jinja, but I need the string to be rendered in one line, and if we do:

```
{% for version in all_python_version %}
{% if version[0] >= list_python_version[0] and version[1] >= list_python_version[1] %}
{{ version[0] ~ '.' ~ version[1] ~ ',' }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Each version will render in its own line, with the last `,` also being rendered.

Is there a way to do get the versions to be rendered in a single line in pure Jinja and its plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conveniently enough, since Jinja allows you to access elements of a list via both `list[0]` and `list.0`, this means that you can actually use a dictionary filter on a list.

And [`selectattr`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.selectattr) is just the filter we need here, since it allows to select items out of a list of dictionaries based on a property of those dictionaries.

Still, we cannot properly fit a logical `and` in there, so we'll need to split the logic in two:

- all Python versions where the major version is strictly equal to our comparison point and the minor version is greater or equal
- all Python versions where the major version is greater than our comparison point, regardless of the minor version

So, we end up with a quite lengthy:

```
{{ 
  all_python_version 
    | selectattr(0, '==', list_python_version.0) 
    | selectattr(1, '>=', list_python_version.1) | list 
  + all_python_version | selectattr(0, '>', list_python_version.0) | list 
}}
```

---

The snippet

```
{%- set list_python_version = [3, 9] -%}
{%- set all_python_version = [
  [3, 8], [3, 9], [3, 10], [3, 11], [3, 12],
] -%}

{{ 
  all_python_version 
    | selectattr(0, '==', list_python_version.0) 
    | selectattr(1, '>=', list_python_version.1) | list 
  + all_python_version | selectattr(0, '>', list_python_version.0) | list 
}}
```

Would yield:

```py
[[3, 9], [3, 10], [3, 11], [3, 12]]
```

---

Then to join everything together, use a combination of [`map`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map) and [`join`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map) in the list of lists and a simple `join` in the resulting list:

```
{{ 
  (
    all_python_version 
      | selectattr(0, '==', list_python_version.0) 
      | selectattr(1, '>=', list_python_version.1) | list 
    + all_python_version | selectattr(0, '>', list_python_version.0) | list
  ) | map('join', '.') | join(', ')
}}
```

Giving

```
3.9, 3.10, 3.11, 3.12
```

Comment: Loved this approach with pipes and filters! But I'm struggling to get the last part, which is to print the list as joined strings forming `"3.9, 3.10, 3.11, 3.12"`, how can this be achieved in Jinja2?

Comment: Oh. I didn't get that you were expecting a string, not a list of lists, answer updated accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is in the right direction, but to print only in the end the eligible Python version we will need to include a temporary variable that we will populate in your for loop and print only in the end.
To manipulating a variable and retain it outside the loop, we will have to introduce namespace in our Jinja code, simple example can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51880609/5736671)

Adding these to your code, it will turn to something like this:

```
{%- set ns = namespace(myfinalvar="") -%}
{% for version in all_python_version -%}
{% if version[0] >= list_python_version[0] and version[1] >= list_python_version[1] -%}
{% set ns.myfinalvar = ns.myfinalvar + (version[0] | string) + '.' + (version[1] | string) + "," -%}
{% endif -%}
{% endfor -%}
{{ ns.myfinalvar }}
```

which prints:

```
3.9,3.10,3.11,3.12,
```

Please note the use of `minus (-)` at the `-%}` to emit creating whitespace lines in the output.

For a more elegant approach on concatenating the eligible Python versions, you can use a list variable and `str.join()` function:

```
{% set ns = namespace(myfinalvarlist=[]) -%}
{% for version in all_python_version -%}
{% if version[0] >= list_python_version[0] and version[1] >= list_python_version[1] -%}
{% set _ = ns.myfinalvarlist.append(".".join([(version[0] | string), (version[1] | string)])) -%}
{% endif -%}
{% endfor -%}
{{ ",".join(ns.myfinalvarlist) }}
```

which prints:

```
3.9,3.10,3.11,3.12
```